# Android application using offline satellite map

Tags: android, api, offline

I've been browsing the internet for two days now looking for the best way to do this, here is my concern :

I'm currently developing an Android application where the user has to browse a map (preferably satellite view), add markers etc. The problem is that the user will often be in a spot without internet access.

Some info i gathered (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Google earth doesn't have an Android API
- Last Google map api for Android allows the developer to implement his own TileProvider (http://guides.cocoahero.com/google-maps-android-custom-tile-providers.html).
- It's forbidden to cache google maps data

So at the end my questions are :

- Is it possible to use the Android Google Map API to display tiles from another data source than google maps ?
- If so what would be a good source of satellite map, available offline ?

I'm new to Android development so I wanted to ask you guys before trying it out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you investigated Open Street Map?
http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100

Comment: Yes and from what i've seen it's a standard map and not a satellite view. I need to command a drone, and plan tracks for the drone. So i need to see "precisely" the landscape, trees, rocks etc